# Proving that the Gauss map of a compact surface is a diffeo local

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, diffeomorphism

Let $S$ be a compact oriented surface, the Gauss map of $S$ is a diffeo local iff its Gaus curvature is positive everywhere.

My try:

Since $S$ is oriented we can define the Gaus map $N:S\rightarrow S^2$, my ideia  was to use the diferential $dN_{p}: T_{p}S\rightarrow T_{p}S$, $T_{p}S$ is the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$, and show that its injective, so i proved the first part, but i dont know how to prove this because the null vector must not be in $T_{p}S$ to make sense my try.

Besides, i dont know how to prove the second part either, or use the hyphothesis that $S$ is compact, maybe i should define the height function $f(p)=<p,N(p)>$ or something like that, anyone can give me a north to continue?

Comment: What relationships do you know between the Gauss map and the Gauss curvature? Can you prove this simpler statement: "the Gauss map of an oriented surface is a local diffeomorphism if and only if the Gauss curvature is nonzero everywhere"?

Comment: the Gauss curvature is the determinant of the diferential of $N$, so it implies it is a isomorphism and then i get the local difeo?

Comment: Correct. Now you need to work out why the compactness assumption rules out negative curvature - this is really a separate argument.

Comment: there is something about the fact that negative curvature let the second form of $S$ not definite?

Comment: It can be indefinite but still nondegenerate - you need to use the compactness. The idea is to show that the curvature is non-negative at "extreme points" of $S$, which you can define in a few different ways.

Comment: the height function i mencioned would help? i still dont see why the assurange of a extreme point of a define function on $S$ would rule out negatives curvatures

Comment: I think you could show the curvature is positive at a maximum of $\langle p, N(p) \rangle$, but it's probably easier to just use $\langle p,p \rangle$ instead.

Comment: but how should proving that this is true for just one extreme point would descart all another negatives curvatures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S$ and $S^2$ are of the same dimension, the Gauss map $N : S \to S^2$ is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $dN$ is invertible everywhere. From the equation $K = \det dN$ we see that this is true exactly if $K$ is nonzero everywhere.

To show that $N$ being a local diffeomorphism implies $K > 0$ (rather than just $K\ne 0$), we need to use the compactness assumption. Since $S$ is compact, the function $f(p) = |p|^2$ attains a maximum $R^2 = \sup_S f$ somewhere on $S,$ which means geometrically that $S$ is contained within the closed ball $\overline{B(0,R)}$ but touches its boundary. At this point of contact, $S$ must have both principal curvatures $\ge 1/R$ in order to stay within the sphere, and thus the Gauss curvature is positive there. But the curvature of a smooth surface is a continuous function, so since we know $K\ne 0$ everywhere and $K > 0$ somewhere we conclude $K>0$ everywhere.

Comment: how did u prove that the both principal curvatures satisfies that?

Comment: If we rotate our coordinates so the point of contact is $(0,0,R),$ then near this point we know $S$ is the graph of some smooth function $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ with $g(0) = R, \nabla g(0) = 0$, and the second fundamental form at the point of contact is equal to the Hessian $\nabla^2 g(0).$ The fact that $S$ is below the sphere becomes $g(x) \le h(x) = \sqrt{R^2 - |x|^2}.$ Since $g(0) = h(0)$ but $g(x) \le h(x)$, we know $\nabla^2 g \le \nabla^2 h$ from calculus. The Hessian of $h$ has double eigenvalue $1/R$, so we're done.

Comment: Good, there is a problem that i found asking to prove this, i've already solved but i still have some doubts, i like yours but i think that if the way i've solved is correct it would be easier for me to understand, could u take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624940/proving-that-the-gauss-and-mean-curvature-of-a-compact-surface-in-a-closed-disk ?